# How to get original icon color in tab titles?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am using `tabs.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_clock_green);` to put a green icon in the tab title. It is working but the color is black. I have tried with several icons and all icons are showing in black color only. I need this icon to be represented in it's own color

Answer (score 1):

Try below code if it helps.

```
//Code to set icon
tabs.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_clock_green);

//code to set color to your icon
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: I already used this code to solve the issue. Thank you for spending time for me.

Answer (score 1):

Tab icons are given a color and tint of colorOnPrimary if using material design. It may be that color you are getting for your icons

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by `tabs.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);`